# react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.useContext is not a function -- When using Autocomplete in Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui, react-hooks

When I try and create an Autocomplete tag using Material UI, I receive the following error:

[image]

The code for the Autocomplete looks like this:

```html
import React, {useState, useEffect, useContext} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {withStyles} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete'; 

  const top100Films = [
    { title: 'The Shawshank Redemption', year: 1994 },
    { title: 'The Godfather', year: 1972 }
  ]

  function textBar() {

    return (
        <div>       
          return (
            <Autocomplete
            id="combo-box-demo"
            options={top100Films}
            getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
            style={{ width: 300 }}
            renderInput={params => <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />}
            />
         </div>
    )
  }

  export default textBar;
```

From what I read online, this is because I am using older versions of the React dependencies so I updated the dependencies in my package.json in both the client and server file to: 
    "react": "^16.7.0-alpha.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0-alpha.2",

but I am still getting the same issue.

Does anyone know how to solve this? I have had no issue using Textfield tags and Menu tags in the same working directory.

Comment: Hooks were introduced in `16.8`. You might have to update react version

Answer (score -1):

SOLVED: Missed adding a dependency in the client file

Comment: Please do not use answer section for comments. Answering own post means doing some research and answering it